# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.min.js:1

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I'm trying use bower for nodejs project and install jquery+bootstrap with it. But I always get the subject error. I have no idea what's wrong.

The code is here:

```
jsfiddle.net/valsaven/8d6e03um/
```

Folder structure:

**chat**:

- **bower_components**
- **node_modules**
- app.js
- index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your backend code, where you are serving the request, not in front end.

```
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.end(index);
});
```

This code executes for all requests, including `js` and `css` files. So, you will get the content of `index.html` in `js` requests. Thus, Javascript engine shows error while parsing the file containing `html` `<` tags.

**Possible Solution** is to define specific routes.

```
var http = require('http'),
 fs = require('fs'),
 path = require('path'),
 express= require('express'),
 index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');

var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use('/bower_components', express.static('bower_components'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-type': 'text/html'
   });
   res.end(index);
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```